# How to activate Bluetooth programatically in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am unable to turn on my Bluetooth programetically in android. how to do it.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

In Activity:

> BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter =
>   BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();     mBluetoothAdapter.enable();

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```